# Send click to background div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs: One is the background that contains clickable items, and the second is an overlay div that is scrollable.  I would like to be able to click the items in the first div without turning off the scrolling capability of the second div.

Here is an example fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/samlalani/yu832xad/36/

Is this possible?  I would appreciate any suggestions and would prefer not to use jQuery (edit: Using vanilla JavaScript is fine, just not jQuery).  Thank you.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr><td onclick="alert('1')" class="red">111111</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td onclick="alert('3')" class="red">333333</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td onclick="alert('6')" class="red">666666</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
  </table>
  <p>
  The ones, threes and sixes should be clickable, and the magenta div should be scrollable.
  </p>
</div>
<div id="overlay" onclick="overlayClick()">
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut venenatis tempus est, sit amet faucibus neque congue eu. Aliquam porta enim tortor, condimentum auctor urna vehicula eu. Suspendisse blandit sapien sapien, eu volutpat odio venenatis eleifend. Donec imperdiet maximus posuere. Mauris rutrum venenatis massa et sodales. Nullam convallis sodales tellus. Ut sodales sem nec lacus viverra, nec vehicula enim dictum. Nam sed molestie massa. Vestibulum eget dui felis. Mauris consequat mauris nec nibh aliquam dapibus. Phasellus id laoreet est. Donec sit amet egestas ex, id malesuada dui. Donec imperdiet, sapien ac dignissim dignissim, lectus dolor convallis sapien, vel elementum arcu leo vel diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10;
  top: 10;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10;
  top: 10;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: magenta;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function overlayClick() {
  alert('overlayClick');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [elementsFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementsFromPoint) property of document. (For IE/Edge support use [msElementsFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh772121(v=vs.85))).

I've just added a couple of lines to your JS, see the basic snippet below:

```js
function overlayClick(e) {
  alert('overlayClick');
  document.elementsFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY)
  .find(el => el.classList.contains('red') && el.click())
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10;
  top: 10;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10;
  top: 10;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: magenta;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr><td onclick="alert('1')" class="red">111111</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td onclick="alert('3')" class="red">333333</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td onclick="alert('6')" class="red">666666</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
  </table>
  <p>
  The ones, threes and sixes should be clickable, and the magenta div should be scrollable.
  </p>
</div>
<div id="overlay" onclick="overlayClick(event)">
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut venenatis tempus est, sit amet faucibus neque congue eu. Aliquam porta enim tortor, condimentum auctor urna vehicula eu. Suspendisse blandit sapien sapien, eu volutpat odio venenatis eleifend. Donec imperdiet maximus posuere. Mauris rutrum venenatis massa et sodales. Nullam convallis sodales tellus. Ut sodales sem nec lacus viverra, nec vehicula enim dictum. Nam sed molestie massa. Vestibulum eget dui felis. Mauris consequat mauris nec nibh aliquam dapibus. Phasellus id laoreet est. Donec sit amet egestas ex, id malesuada dui. Donec imperdiet, sapien ac dignissim dignissim, lectus dolor convallis sapien, vel elementum arcu leo vel diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution!  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kosh Very, very good solution. I am curious though, if there is any way to get the hover effect to work also?

Comment: @VenesemeTyras, yes this is possible. Listen to `mousemove` events and check whether the element is under the mouse cursor or not.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit (js solution with code) - for pure css alternative, see below

I think Kosh Very's solution is much better. It is much cleaner. I did not know about the elementsFromPoint property.

Yes, I think we can do pretty much everything you asked for with jquery. I  will leave the previous info below just in case someone in the future might find the pure css method useful.

I know you asked for vanilla js and not jquery, but as per comments below I am providing a jquery solution. The same may be possible with vanilla js but it is beyond my skill level, at least the jquery may provide a starting point and may serve others with similar questions in future.

1. Put a generic table with the same size elements as the target table over the overlay, this will function as a click-grid. Set it to `pointer-events:none;`
2. Give the click-grid cells numbered data attributes so we can generically target 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. rows of the target table. Set the click-grid cells `background-color:transparent;`
3. Listen for mousedown on the overlay to enable the pointer-events on the click-grid.
4. Listen for mouseup on the click-grid cells and use their data attributes to target the correct row of the target-table and trigger a click.
5. After triggering the click re-disable click-grid pointer events.
6. On the overlay mousedown function we should also re-disable click-grid pointer events after a short delay in case the user clicks the overlay but not actually on a click-grid cell. So this is a delayed backup to make sure the click-grid pointer-events don't accidentally get left active.

https://jsfiddle.net/rehtnvf8/10/

The only drawback here seems to be that you can't do hover effects on the underlying targets. You weren't doing so before and it was not in your requirements, so I think this should be suitable. I believe it is possible to do the hover effects and probably do this more elegantly using jquery's .mousemove but getting that to work was a little over my head. Also, in the examples the extra elements are written into the html, while it would probably be better, to add them to the page with javascript.

Here is the code sample for reference as well

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //.click-grid .cg-src function fired on mouseup
  $.overlayClick = function(event) {
   //prevent default probably not needed
    event.preventDefault();
    //the table where we find targets
    var tabl = $('.cg-target');
    //the firing element
    var clickSrc = $(event.target);
    //get data attr of firing element
    var clickTrgt = $(clickSrc).data('cgt');
    //use data attr to count down table elements
    //and locate target row
    var tablTrgt = tabl.find('tr').eq(clickTrgt);
    //find td within target row and trigger click
    tablTrgt.find('td').trigger('click');
    //disable pointer events on .click-grid
    $('.click-grid').css('pointer-events', 'none');
  }
  //#overlay function fired on mousedown
  $.overlayDown = function() {
   //mousedown on #overlay enable .click-grid pointer-events
    $('.click-grid').css('pointer-events', 'all');
    //in case click was not over .cg-src
    //disable .click-grid pointer events after short delay
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.click-grid').css('pointer-events', 'none');
    }, 300);
  }
  //listen for clicks, mousedown on #overlay, mouseup on cg-src
  $(document).on('mousedown', '#overlay', $.overlayDown);
  $('.click-grid').on('mouseup', '.cg-src', $.overlayClick);

});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10;
  top: 10;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10;
  top: 10;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: magenta;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.scroll-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
td {
  height: 1.2em;
}
.click-grid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10;
  left: 10;
  z-index: 10;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.click-grid td {
  width: 4em;
  height: 1.2em;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
}
.red:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <table class="cg-target">
    <tr><td onclick="alert('1')" class="red red-1">111111</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="no-pointer">2</td></tr>
    <tr><td onclick="alert('3')" class="red">333333</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td onclick="alert('6')" class="red">666666</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
  </table>
  <p>
  The ones, threes and sixes should be clickable, and the magenta div should be scrollable.
  </p>
</div>
<div id=overlay>
  <div class="scroll-content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut venenatis tempus est, sit amet faucibus neque congue eu. Aliquam porta enim tortor, condimentum auctor urna vehicula eu. Suspendisse blandit sapien sapien, eu volutpat odio venenatis eleifend. Donec imperdiet maximus posuere. Mauris rutrum venenatis massa et sodales. Nullam convallis sodales tellus. Ut sodales sem nec lacus viverra, nec vehicula enim dictum. Nam sed molestie massa. Vestibulum eget dui felis. Mauris consequat mauris nec nibh aliquam dapibus. Phasellus id laoreet est. Donec sit amet egestas ex, id malesuada dui. Donec imperdiet, sapien ac dignissim dignissim, lectus dolor convallis sapien, vel elementum arcu leo vel diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  </div>
</div>
<table class="click-grid">
  <tr><td class="cg-src" data-cgt="0"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="cg-src" data-cgt="1"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="cg-src" data-cgt="2"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="cg-src" data-cgt="3"></td></tr>
</table>
```

### Original Answer (pure css)

Okay, so what you are trying to do, is not really possible with pure html/css. Maybe you could do with javascript.

That said, using pure css, we can get fairly close to what you are after by putting some of the table elements inside the overlay. We can use `position: fixed;` so they are taken out of the layout flow, and z-index to put them behind the text. Then we use `pointer-events: none;` on the div containing the text.

Note that the `pointer-events` property in css has pretty good support at this point yet is still technically considered 'experimental,' so caution should be exercised before using it in production.

https://jsfiddle.net/ako05wpr/3/

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr><td onclick="alert('1')" class="red">111111</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="no-pointer">2</td></tr>
    <tr><td onclick="alert('3')" class="red">333333</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td onclick="alert('6')" class="red">666666</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
  </table>
  <p>
  The ones, threes and sixes should be clickable, and the magenta div should be scrollable.
  </p>
</div>
<div id="overlay" onclick="overlayClick()">
  <table class="behind">
    <tr><td onclick="alert('1')" class="red">111111</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td onclick="alert('3')" class="red">333333</td></tr>
  </table>
  <div class="scroll-content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut venenatis tempus est, sit amet faucibus neque congue eu. Aliquam porta enim tortor, condimentum auctor urna vehicula eu. Suspendisse blandit sapien sapien, eu volutpat odio venenatis eleifend. Donec imperdiet maximus posuere. Mauris rutrum venenatis massa et sodales. Nullam convallis sodales tellus. Ut sodales sem nec lacus viverra, nec vehicula enim dictum. Nam sed molestie massa. Vestibulum eget dui felis. Mauris consequat mauris nec nibh aliquam dapibus. Phasellus id laoreet est. Donec sit amet egestas ex, id malesuada dui. Donec imperdiet, sapien ac dignissim dignissim, lectus dolor convallis sapien, vel elementum arcu leo vel diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  </div>
</div>
```

```
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10;
  top: 10;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10;
  top: 10;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: magenta;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.scroll-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.behind {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
.behind, .behind tr, .behind td {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.behind tr td.red {
  pointer-events: all;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
}
.red:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
}
```

I used smaller table which only duplicates those first three rows, and covers those same three rows of the original table. Alternatively you could remove those rows from the original table and position under the overlay.

I think this is quite close to your goal. The issue remains though, that when hovering the `.red` clickable table elements behind the text, the text is not scrollable simultaneously. I minimized this by setting `pointer-events: none;` on all the table elements except `.red` so it is only the actual button itself which inhibits scrolling. This is not possible to overcome with just css. as the mouse can not interact with two elements simultaneously.

You can effect a child or direct sibling of an element you interact with, but that is indirectly. You aren't actually interacting with multiple elements. Only interacting with the one element, which is indirectly effecting style changes on children or direct siblings, and you can't do scrolling like that.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and your methodology is very interesting.  However, the background div will be created with a different process which I do not have control over, so I cannot add the TR/TD values on the overlay div.  By the way, I am okay with using vanilla JavaScript, just would prefer not to use jQuery.

Comment: To clarify my comment above, I can suggest changes to the background div, such as html/css changes, but a lot of it will be created based on live data, so I cannot add those TR/TD values on the overlay div.

Comment: Well, maybe you could duplicate the entire table within the overlay div. That may be easier than breaking off a fragment like I did, and it would work the same, just the lower portion would be cuttoff, so you would want it to be a duplicate rather than just moving the one table.

Comment: Because the links also turn off the capability of being able to scroll when the mouse is over those TD values, and there may be a lot of links in the background div, I cannot use this methodology.  But I appreciate the attempt.  I think I need to capture the click in the overlay div and then dispatch it to the background div, I just don't know how to do that at this time.  Any help with that would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay, I'm not great with javascript, but I'm pretty sure you can do it fairly easily. I edited my answer to include a javascript method that I think will work. When I have some more time this afternoon I can probably workup the jquery to show an example, but I'm not familiar enough with vanilla js to do it that way, though I imagine it is possible.

Comment: If you can create a jQuery example, it would be great for now, and then later I can try to convert it to vanilla JS.  Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: Edited answer with jquery solution.

Comment: Thank you Veneseme, it is great that you got it to work.  As you said, though, that Kosh Very's solution using the elementsFromPoint property is much cleaner, but I appreciate the time you spent and the code you provided.  I am sure it will be useful in some different cases.

Answer (score 0):

This, unfortunately, is not possible. You can use `pointer-events: none;` to make the overlaying div "transparent" to the mouse, but that also means that it cannot be scrolled.

Comment: Isn't there a way to catch the click event in the overlay div and then dispatch it to the underlying div?

Comment: I guess you could get the coordinates of the mouse click relative to the entire page but only inside the div using the onclick event, then find the position and size of the clickable elements below the div, check if the mouse click is inside the coordinates, then execute a function on click. But that's kind of hacky and not pure HTML/CSS. I'll try and update my answer if I have time to write that out later this week.